# how to pass condtion file in awk program? I have one file of conditions and one input file in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have one file of conditions and one input file in awk. i want to execute condition one by one in awk program. how to pass condition in awk program?

```
cond.txt
---------
a[NR-1]==a[NR-2] && b[NR-1] > 0 && c[NR-1] > 0 && d[NR-1] > 0
a[NR-1]==a[NR-2] && b[NR-1] > 0 && c[NR-1] > 0 && d[NR-1] < 0
a[NR-1]==a[NR-2] && b[NR-1] > 0 && c[NR-1] < 0 && d[NR-1] > 0
a[NR-1]==a[NR-2] && b[NR-1] > 0 && c[NR-1] < 0 && d[NR-1] < 0
---------
 prog.sh
--------
while read aa
do 
((d++))
awk -v CC="$aa"  -F ";" '{ a[NR]=$1;b[NR]=$2;c[NR]=$3;d[NR]=$4;if(CC){ printf "%s;%8.2f;%8.2f;%8.2f; \n",$1,$2,$3,$4 } }' input > output-$d
done <cond.txt

input
--------
 p; -415.98;    428.49;   -422.24;
 p;  232.55;    234.85;   233.7;
 p; -440.35;    444.42;   -442.38;
 p;  17.05;         17.09;    17.07;
 p;  351.25;        -355.35;  -353.3;
 p; 366.89;         -371.28;  369.08;
 n; 11.97;          12.17;    12.07;
 n; 506.93;         509.15;   508.04;
 n; 306.9;          314.7;    310.8;
 n; 381.1;          381.94;   381.52;
 n; 84.12;          84.33;    84.22;
 n; 237.36;         240.73;   239.05;
 n; 345.51;         352.49;   349;

 Thanks You in advance
```

Answer (score 2):

That is an unusual and somewhat unconventional arrangement, and potentially insecure. But you can use the shell to generate the Awk script from the input strings. You almost had it -- just use the shell's variable interpolation to inject the condition into the string you pass to Awk.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r cond; do
    ((+d))
    awk -F ";" "$cond"'{ printf "%s;%8.2f;%8.2f;%8.2f; \n",$1,$2,$3,$4 } }' input > output-$d
done <cond.txt
```

The arrays in the script were not used for anything so I took them out.

The ((arithmetic)) is a Bash feature so I changed the shebang. Notice also the use of `read -r` to avoid the pesky legacy default behavior of `read`.

The conditions seem to be rather tightly coupled to your solution so I would perhaps embed them in a here document rather than store them in a separate file.

Comment: exactly what I want to say :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure `-v` is the right way to do it. But you can achieve the same goal through bash variable like this:

```
while read condition; do awk '{ if('"$condition"') { ... }}' input; done < cond.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Why? To parse the same file 4 times testing a different condition each time, just do this instead:

```
awk -F';' '
BEGIN { for (i=1; i<=4; i++) { ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGC++ } }
{ a[FNR]=$1; b[FNR]=$2; c[FNR]=$3; d[FNR]=$4 }
(ARGIND==1 && a[FNR-1]==a[FNR-2] && b[FNR-1] > 0 && c[FNR-1] > 0 && d[FNR-1] > 0) ||
(ARGIND==2 && a[FNR-1]==a[FNR-2] && b[FNR-1] > 0 && c[FNR-1] > 0 && d[FNR-1] < 0) ||
(ARGIND==3 && a[FNR-1]==a[FNR-2] && b[FNR-1] > 0 && c[FNR-1] < 0 && d[FNR-1] > 0) ||
(ARGIND==4 && a[FNR-1]==a[FNR-2] && b[FNR-1] > 0 && c[FNR-1] < 0 && d[FNR-1] < 0) {
    printf "%s;%8.2f;%8.2f;%8.2f; \n",$1,$2,$3,$4 > (output"-"ARGIND)
}
' input
```

The above uses gawks ARGIND to determine which iteration of reading the file you're on. if you don't have that just add a line at the top that says `FNR==1{++ARGIND}`.